# I want allow user to insert data in particular month column as basis on given period

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
  This period detail
    period 1 =  1/1/2016  to 31/1/2016
    period 2 =   2/2/2016 to  30/2/2016
    period 1 =  1/3/2016  to 31/3/2016
    period 2 =   2/4/2016 to  30/4/2016
    period 1 =  1/5/2016  to 31/5/2016
    period 2 =   2/6/2016 to  30/6/2016
    period 1 =  1/7/2016  to 31/7/2016
    period 2 =   2/8/2016 to  30/8/2016
    period 1 =  1/9/2016  to 31/9/2016
    period 2 =  2/10/2016 to 30/10/2016
    period 1 =  1/1/2016  to 31/11/2016
    period 2 =  2/1/2016  to 30/12/2016
```

and I having another table which contains all month as column name and data type is int

```
Jan Feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec
```

then actual problem  starts now If I am choosing period 1 then only i can insert value in jan month for other month it has to show error like 'selected period and enter month are not same'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if @monthsht    =   'JAN'
begin
    if isnull(@_february,0) <>  0        or isnull(@_march,0)       <>  0   or      isnull(@_april,0)       <>  0   or
       isnull(@_may,0)      <>  0        or isnull(@_june,0)        <>  0   or      isnull(@_july,0)        <>  0   or
       isnull(@_august,0)   <>  0        or isnull(@_september,0)   <>  0   or      isnull(@_october,0)     <>  0   or
       isnull(@_november,0) <>  0        or isnull(@_december,0)    <>  0       

       begin
            raiserror('The Period or the month for which the values are entered are of not the same period',16,1)
            return
       end
```